# select group concat with join tables or move data to one column text datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have Author and Books tables.

My current method to select data is I LEFT JOIN books table to Author table and use GROUP_CONCAT to get the list of books.

As the number of books increases it looks like query is becoming slow.

I was thinking to add another column for list of books with text datatype and store all the books as text. So that I only have to use one SELECT from one table.

Would query be faster and better if I use one large text column instead of group_concat?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Show us the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I don't think `GROUP_CONCAT` is the villain, but I need to see more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Would query be faster and better if I use one large text column
> instead of group_concat?

Obviously that query will run faster.

**BUT**

managing the list of books will be overhead, as for each DML in `books` table you will have to update the list of books in `author` table.

This is not considered as a good practice. Instead, you can concentrate on making your `LEFT JOIN` query faster by index or any other performance technique.

Comment: It's not obvious to me :-(